# How to replace console output to text based on some states using awk?

Tags: awk, grep, cut

Hi I would like to parse some data and for certain values replace it to a string before saving to a CSV

```
Sample Lines
============
Time,11,Name,Jack,Cost,1300,Paid,1
Time,13,Name,Tim,Cost,1300,Paid,0

grep & cut (&awk)
============
grep -i "Time,\d+,Name,\w+,Cost,\d+,Paid" | cut -d, -f2 -f4 -f6 -f7 | awk (replace f7 with True if 1 or replace f7 with False if 0)
```

Thanks

EDIT: Fixed my grep.

Comment: For future uses of `cut`. you can separate multiple fields with a comma: `-f2,4,6,7`

Answer (score 3):

It is always good to give both input and output example.

awk could do it alone, without grep and cut. try this line:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$8=$8==1?"True":"False";print $2,$4,$6,$8}' file
```

with your data, the awk line gives:

```
11,Jack,1300,True
13,Tim,1300,False
```

Comment: The OP also has a (poorly formed) grep; you should limit the scope with a pattern.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I assume that those labels (grep pattern) exist in every line. It may be true or not true. If he had problem on this part, I would help. and his grep pattern won't return any result from his input.

Comment: @kent Yes those pattern exist in every line. Thanks for the pure awk implementation.

Comment: @amehta if the answer solved your question, how about consider to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r 's/\S+,(\S+,)\S+,(\S+,)\S+,(\S+,)\S+,(.)/\1\2\3\4/;s/1$/True/;s/0$/False/' file
```

---

```
$ cat file
Time,11,Name,Jack,Cost,1300,Paid,1
Time,13,Name,Tim,Cost,1300,Paid,0

$ sed -r 's/\S+,(\S+,)\S+,(\S+,)\S+,(\S+,)\S+,(.)/\1\2\3\4/;s/1$/True/;s/0$/False/' file
11,Jack,1300,True
13,Tim,1300,False
```